# How to enter time in a cell of excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In this photo, as you see I have entered the formula `=TIME(6,28,38.117)` in the `B33` cell. But I don't understand why the content is shown like: `28:38.0`.
I mean why the hour isn't shown and how can I set excel in order to not approximate the data and print all those 3 decimal digits for the seconds?
I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010 on a win7x64 machine.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to change to display the hour and the 3 decimal digits for the seconds.

First, format the cell as `hh:mm:ss.000` for `06:28:38.117`, or `h:mm:ss.000` for `6:28:38.117` (i.e., hours with or without a leading zero). Add these special time formats in the Custom category of the Format Cells... window.

[image: format cells]

The other problem is that the `TIME` function accepts **whole seconds** and quietly ignores the fractional part. There are two ways to work around that limitation.

1. Add the fractional seconds, converted to days, to the result of the `TIME` function. For example:

```
=TIME(6,28,38)+0.117/(24*3600)
```

2. Use the `TIMEVALUE` function which accepts fractional seconds:

```
=TIMEVALUE("6:28:38.117")
```

Comment: ok, formatting is a good idea. but i could find any format for the leading zero. as this images show: [image1](http://i.imgur.com/zHqVZfz.jpg) and [image2](http://i.imgur.com/X2VvBGz.jpg). Also non of the tricks work for showing the decimal (fractional) part of the seconds. [image 1](http://i.imgur.com/Dj7eYok.jpg) and [image 2](http://i.imgur.com/OzfwexH.jpg).

Comment: Go the Custom category, not the Time category, on the Format Cells window. That's where you can type or paste the formats. I'll update the answer.

Comment: yeh, i did it before your comment. with the custom, both of your tricks work. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried formatting the cell (B33) to your liking?

**Right-click** on the cell, select **Format Cells...**, and select the category and formatting option you desire.

[image: Format Cells]